# batch update in codeigniter with simple array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

I want to do a batch update in codeignter and pass the array data, instead of running multiple queries.

```
Array ( [439] => 0 [440] => 0 [441] => 0 [442] => 1 [443] => 0 )
```

The 439, 440, 441, 442, 443 are the id's and the 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 are the values that need to be put into the active column.

I can achieve this running it thru a loop, but I want to do a batch update.

```
foreach($this->input->post($field_name) as $key => $value)
{
    $insert = array(
        'id'        =>  $key,
        'active'    =>  $value,
    );

    $this->db->where('id', $key)->update($table, array('active' => $value));
}
```

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Comment: Interesting. When you enable the output profiler on the view, what comes up for the database queries?

Answer (score 0):

Build the array with a foreach loop, then use the batch update.

**EDIT:** I forgot the second `array()` in the opening array. It may or may not be needed.

```
$data = array(array());

foreach($this->input->post($field_name) as $key => $value)
{
    $push = array(
        'id'        =>  $key,
        'active'    =>  $value,
    );
array_push($data, $push);
}
$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

loop through your array and use an associative array to store the data

```
foreach($this->input->post($field_name) as $key => $value)
{
  $insert[] = array(
     'id'        =>  $key,
     'active'    =>  $value
  );

}   
$this->db->update_batch('yourtable', $insert, 'id');
```